# .find() not working as expected after creating node list from HTML snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following Javascript code using jQuery:

```
var html = '<a href="http://foo.example.com">Foo/a> | ' + 
           '<a href="http://bar.example.com">Bar</a>';
var aTags = $(html).find('a');
console.log(aTags.length); // => 0
```

Why is `aTags` an empty array and not an array of 2 `<a>` nodes?

Comment: `var aTags = $(html).filter('a');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `filter()` because `find()` tries to find the descendant element of elements referred by the jQuery object, in your string the `a` elements are at the root so `find()` will not be able to find them

```js
var html = '<a href="http://foo.example.com">Foo/a> | ' +
  '<a href="http://bar.example.com">Bar</a>';
var aTags = $(html).filter('a');
snippet.log(aTags.length); // => 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```